# How to integrate Swagger editor in Lumen/Laravel for REST API?

Tags: laravel-8, lumen, php-8

I have built some REST API in Lumen micro framework and it's working fine. Now I want to integrate Swagger editor into it so the API will be well documented on future use. Has anyone done this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you looked into this library: https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume ?

Comment: I need integrate with swagger editor not with swigger lume  in Lumen/Laravel for rest api.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense to me. It seems like asking how to integrate Notepad++ or VSCode: as far as I know, Swagger Editor is a tool for *humans* to work with Open API Spec files, not something you'd "integrate".